# Xcode 6 Sound on button

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I making a simple soundboard and I'm trying to make my button make a sound when pressed, but when I run the simulator nothing plays. This is my code -

ViewController.m

```
    #import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(IBAction)sound1 {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"sound1", CFSTR("wav"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

-(IBAction)sound1;



@end
```

and also how to I link up the button up with the sound??

Comment: Do you mean that you haven't linked the button up to the IBAction?

Comment: I think so but how do I do that?

Comment: Why not first try to `NSLog` in your `sound1` method and see if it works when the button is clicked?

Comment: I got this code from a tutorial and some reason it doesnt work in xcode 6, does anyone know the code to just play a sound from a button?

Comment: I don't think it's Xcode 6. You seem to be lacking a basic understanding of iOS development. I'm not being rude, I'm making an observation. Is there a .xib file associated with this view controller?

Comment: The sound id must be stored in a property, not on the stack where it gets cleared immediately

Comment: there is only a LanchScreen.xib

Comment: You need to hook up the action to the button. There's better ways of doing it, and you should read up on general iOS development - Code School is pretty solid - but you can at least check to see if the code to play the sound is working by manually adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to the button in the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Have you tried to debug and read documentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't use wav as it takes up too much memory, mp3 is better. Second this has got nothing to do with Xcode 6. Third you may have not imported the AudioToolBox file in your linked frameworks and Libraries.

Do this in the .h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
IBOutlet UIButton *SoundButton;
}
@end
```

Do This is the .m file

```
-(IBAction)Sound:(id)sender
{
NSLog("Button is pressed");
NSString *over = @"sound1";
SystemSoundID soundID;
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:over ofType:@"wav"];
NSURL *soundUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath];
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID ((__bridge CFURLRef)soundUrl, &soundID);
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

SoundButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
SoundButton.frame = CGRectMake(X cord, Y cord, width, height);
[SoundButton addTarget:self action:@selector(Sound:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

I advise you to learn and how to use Xcode and Objective-C / Swift before asking questions such as these.

Comment: I just tried that and when I run it and press the button the sound doesn't play but it does show "Button is pressed" in the log

Comment: It doesn't work on the simulator, but it does work on the device